# Why does the computer take a longer time to start than to shut down?

Tags: networking

Why does my system take more time to start than to shut down?

Comment: I don't understand your question - was there something in particular you wanted to ask? Is there something you're seeing that you think is strange?

Comment: hi, Mr. James Polley. When i start my computer it will take time to display the desktop and desktop items. when i shutdown it take less time to turnoff ? why like tahat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because when you're starting up, your computer has to load drivers from disk, into RAM, using your CPU. It has to load the OS kernel, initialise and begin displaying pictures via your VDU, start sounding... sound, so on. When you're shutting down, it has to safely turn off devices, and save settings, and so, and... not much else!

So the reason it takes longer to turn on, is because it's doing more. A lot more.

Comment: hi Mr. Phoshi, you mean when computer start all the service should satart it take time to start,  am i right?

Comment: Yes, exactly, it has a lot to do when it's starting up, but not as much when it's shutting down! :D

Comment: ya i understood thank you Mr. Phoshi good explanation